# libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 present in /usr/local/lib but executable needs libopencv_features2d.so.2.3

Tags: 14.04, opencv

I am a newbie so if this question has been previously asked or it is too rudimentary, please go easy on me and be helpful.

I have installed opencv-2.4.0 and now I am working on terrain classification code. I am getting the following error while running the loader, `./terrClass`.

```
error while loading shared libraries: 
libopencv_features2d.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the solution of

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

but the thing is in my `/usr/local/lib` directory, `libopencv_features2d.so.2.4` is present, not `libopencv_features2d.so.2.3`. 
What should I do now. Should I degrade `libopencv_features2d.so.2.4` to `libopencv_features2d.so.2.3` or what ?

One more thing I should tell you guys. There is a main directory called, `terrClass` and then there is a subdirectory `src`. There are two executables, one in the main directory called `terrClass` and one in the subdirectory `src` also called, `terrClass` .This executable runs fine without any errors in the main directory but in `src` directory it is giving the error as mentioned above.

Should I try to eliminate this error before going any further with code or is it okay that I use the executable of the main directory and ignore the one in the `src` directory.

Comment: Ignore the executable in the `src` directory. It's probably not supposed to be executed directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the package `libopencv-features2d2.3`, which is not available for `trusty` or for `utopic`, but that is still available for `precise`; you can add the `universe` repository for `precise` to your `apt` repositories by adding these lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
```

Then you can install `libopencv-features2d2.3` by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libopencv-features2d2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Subsequent library versions often contain a superset of the API symbols and features of the previous version. It may be enough to create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.3
```